# What does ArraysKt__ArraysKt mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I inspect the proguard-file of an Android Project using Kotlin, I find the usage of `ArraysKt___ArraysKt` which can't be found in the source code or code decoded from the apk.

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt {
    boolean contains(java.lang.Object[],java.lang.Object);
    java.lang.Object lastOrNull(java.lang.Object[]);
    ...
}
```

My question is that is this `ArraysKt___ArraysKt` a middle generated code that will be converted to other forms at the end? Why do I need to keep like this rather than `ArraysKt`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Metadata(bv = {1, 0, 3}, d1 = {"kotlin/collections/ArraysKt__ArraysJVMKt", "kotlin/collections/ArraysKt__ArraysKt", "kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysJvmKt", "kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysKt"}, k = 4, mv = {1, 1, 16}, xi = 1)
public final class ArraysKt extends j {
    private static transient /* synthetic */ boolean[] $jacocoData;

    private static /* synthetic */ boolean[] $jacocoInit() {
        boolean[] zArr = $jacocoData;
        if (zArr != null) {
            return zArr;
        }
        boolean[] probes = Offline.getProbes(425438020571662420L, "kotlin/collections/ArraysKt", 1);
        $jacocoData = probes;
        return probes;
    }

    private ArraysKt() {
        $jacocoInit()[0] = true;
    }
}
```

This piece of code is decoded from an apk, and the Metadata somehow leaks the information about where this file comes from. It is created by the compiler and injected with multiple files defined in the `d1` field. These files are also created on the fly by the compiler.

Please correct me if you find this conclusion is wrong.